# FreeRTOS Struct as parameter to create task

Tags: c, struct, task, freertos

I am trying to give my task in FreeRTOS a Struct as parameter.

When I create a Struct such as:

```
typedef struct taskParameters
{
    uint8_t taskNr;
} taskParameters;
```

Which I give values in my main function outside of the task like:

```
    uint8_t n = 5;
    struct taskParameters *taskPtr;
    taskPtr = (struct taskParameters *)malloc(n * sizeof(struct taskParameters));
    uint8_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        (taskPtr + i)->taskNr = i;
        xTaskCreate(&taskFunction, "RandomName", 2048, (taskPtr + i), 5, NULL);
    }
```

When I then try to extract the values from this struct in my taskFunction like:

```
    taskParameters parameter = *(taskParameters *)param;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Task: %d\n", &parameter.taskNr);
```

I get a "random" value which does stay the same during the entire process.

But when I print the values of the struct outside of the task the values are correct.

Any ideas?
I did read something about not being able to pass "stack variables", but it did not really get me further. (I am rather new to C as well as FreeRTOS).

I tried googling for different methods, but I found a source that did say it was possible but not how. Furthermore I tried to make the struct global or static consts, since I also read that somewhere.

Comment: We don't have the full context of your code. If you are doing the malloc from a function that returns, `taskPtr` will go out of scope and you'll get garbage accessing it afterwords, also polluting memory as the malloc'ed will never be retrieved. `taskPtr` should have persistent storage.

Comment: your `printf()` prints the address `&parameter.taskNr` but not `taskNr` itself

Comment: `malloc` does not look good .... never use

Comment: `&parameter.taskNr` i think you need to reread your C book

Comment: @ensc Thank you! I completely overlooked that